# Why is $N(ab)=NaNb$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $a,b\in G$ can someone explain why $N(ab)=NaNb$? I know it's trivial but just can't see why.

Comment: the key is that $NN = N$.

Comment: For a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ each left coset is equal to the right coset. In particular $aN=Na$ for all $a\in G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
N(ab) &= (Na)b \\
      &= (aN)b \tag{$N$ normal} \\
      &= (a N^2) b \tag{$N^2 = N$} \\
      &= (aN)(Nb) \\
      &= (Na)(Nb), \tag{$N$ normal}
\end{align} where the first and fourth steps are justified by the associativity of the group operation.

---

If you are not comfortable with the first and fourth steps, it will be a good exercise for you to show that for each $a, b \in G$ and $M, N \subseteq G$ that

\begin{align}
a(MN) &= (aM)N, \\
(MN)a &= M(Na), \\
(ab)M &= a(bM), \\
M(ab) &= (Ma)b.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Noting $Nb = bN$ and realizing $N =NN$ because $N$ is a subgroup we have:

\begin{equation}
(Na)(Nb) = N(aN)b = N(Na)b = NN ab = N (ab)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y\in N$, then $xayb\in N(ab)$ because $xayb(ab)^{-1}=xaya^{-1}=x(aya^{-1})$. By normality, $aya^{-1}\in N$, therefore $xayb(ab)^{-1}\in N$. On the other hand, $xab\in NaNb$ for all $x\in N$, because $xa\in Na$ and $b\in Nb$.